# Piechart using morris.js not working (raphael.js is giving error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, morris.js

I am drawing pie charts using morris.js. When I am loading the page, I am getting 
"Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M,0,0"" & Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="Z". My code is as follows.

**Code:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/lib/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload = onLoading()>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BNG Subscriber Analytics</a>
            </div>

    </nav>
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="i1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="i2"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="i3"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="i4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="i5"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="i6"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="i7"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="i8"></div>
            </div>


</body>

<script src="static/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

 });

function onLoading()
{
 alert("Page Loaded");
  Morris.Donut({
  element: 'i1',
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ]
});

Morris.Donut({
  element: 'i2',
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ]
});

Morris.Donut({
  element: 'i3',
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ]
});

Morris.Donut({
  element: 'i4',
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ]
});

Morris.Donut({
  element: 'i5',
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ]
});

Morris.Donut({
  element: 'i6',
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ]
});

Morris.Donut({
  element: 'i7',
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ]
});
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'i8',
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ]
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code and had no errors. The donuts are correctly displayed.

Comment: May I know which versions of raphael-min.js and morris.min.js you used? I have been trying this for the last 2 hours but could not succeed. Also please tell me if there is any diff in your code and mine. Thanks :)

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it was working. The only difference I see is that I have not your css classes from your static folder. Maybe a css bootstrap class issue ?